# MySQL sorting by "relationships per day"

Tags: mysql, sorting

I need to create a mysql query for my project that's a bit too complicated for my scope...

So, I a table of images with id and timestamp columns, along with metadata columns

I also have a table of "loves", which has columns for id, imageid, userid, and timestamp

(userid not really important here)

Currently, I am using a LEFT JOIN to sort the images by their total number of likes

What I would like to do now is, instead, sort the images by their daily average of likes.

So, an image created today that has 5 likes associated with it should come before an image created 5 days ago with 20 likes associated.

Not even sure how to begin to approach this, any of you SQL gurus have any ideas? Cheers.

EDIT:

Using this query

```
SELECT images.*, 
COUNT(loves.id) AS num_loves 
FROM images 
JOIN loves ON (images.id = loves.imageid) 
GROUP BY images.id 
ORDER BY num_loves/DATEDIFF(images.timestamp,CURDATE()) 
DESC LIMIT 0 , 24
```

getting this error

`Reference 'num_loves' not supported (reference to group function)`

Still getting a handle on MySQL syntax...

Comment: Well, an obvious first step would be to calculate the "daily average of likes". Can you do that part? Once you have that, all you need to do is join and order by. Have a go yourself first, and if you get stuck, post your code and show what doesn't work.

Comment: Count all likes for an image, then by [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), with upload date and `DATE()`, count how many days it is and then divide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any valid expression as your `ORDER BY` clause. This means we just need to recall a hint of algebra:

```
SELECT 
  images.url,
  images.date_added
FROM IMAGES
JOIN image_likes ON image_likes.image_id = images.id
GROUP BY images.id
ORDER BY count(image_likes.id)/DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), images.date_added)
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, and it should work, but I am getting an error back. Here's my query and the error. Also please note the names are a bit different. The tables are called "images" and "loves" in my database.  Query: `SELECT images.*, COUNT(loves.id) AS num_loves FROM images JOIN loves ON (images.id = loves.imageid) GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY num_loves/DATEDIFF(a.timestamp,CURDATE()) DESC LIMIT 0 , 24`, error: `Reference 'num_loves' not supported (reference to group function)` - what have I done wrong? I understand what I need to be doing, I'm just no good at SQL syntax...

Comment: Editing my question with more readable versions of what I posted in my comment

Comment: Okay, I was wrong about the alias part. I did some testing and I get the same error when using an alias, but not when putting the actual aggregate function in the ORDER clause. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, working as expected now. I feel like I understand MySQL's syntax a bit better now. Thank you!